# Iterate inside a nested child. Firebase and Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Here is my data structure:

```
{ "ItemData": {
    "Item": [
      {
        "name": "Table",
        "measurement ": [
          {
            "height": 30
          },
          {
            "width": 50
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I can currently fetch all the data from Firebase and able to display the name on to a tableView. I am now trying to get the values that are nested inside the 'measurement' i.e. 'height' & 'width'. I have looked at [Query Firebase for nested child swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780311/query-firebase-for-nested-child-swift), [What's the best way of structuring data on firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421179/whats-the-best-way-of-structuring-data-on-firebase/16423316#16423316), [Iterate through nested snapshot children in Firebase using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892294/iterate-through-nested-snapshot-children-in-firebase-using-swift) and [Firebase Swift 3 Xcode 8 - iterate through observe results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40980821/firebase-swift-3-xcode-8-iterate-through-observe-results) but still have no clue how to solve this.

This is my Item class:

```
class Item {

    var name: String!
    var measurement: String!
    var key: String

    init(from snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]

        self.name = snapshotValue!["name"] as! String
        self.measurement = snapshotValue?["measurement"] as! String
        self.key = snapshot.key

    }
}
```

This is the function I use to fetch the item. The ItemManager is a class that has the function to remove and add the array of Item:

```
func fetchItem() {

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "ItemData/Item/")

    databaseRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        ItemManager.shared.removeAll()
        for item in snapshot.children {
            guard let snapshot = item as? FIRDataSnapshot else { continue }


            let item = Item(from: snapshot)
            ItemManager.shared.additem(item)
            print(snapshot)
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

}
```

Please help me if you can :)

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: Your first problem is that `measurement` is an array, so all its elements should be of the same type. However, you use the first element for `height` and the next for `width`. If you have control over this, change measurement to be a dictionary. That way, it'll be easy to retrieve `width` and `height`.

Comment: @PedroCastilho I am not getting any error. I am just trying to get the values inside measurement.

Comment: @paulvs Thanks for this advice and I get what you mean, however I'm not sure how to implement this change. Do I just make the measurement be an NSDictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in comment `measurement` array of dictionary not the String, So if you want to get `height` and `width` from it you can get it this way.

```
class Item {

    var name: String!
    var heightMeasurement: String!
    var widthMeasurement: String!
    var key: String

    init(from snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]

        self.name = snapshotValue!["name"] as! String
        if let array = snapshotValue["measurement"] as? [[String:Any]], 
           let heightDic = array.first, let height = heightDic["height"],
           let widthDic = array.last, let width = widthDic["width"] {            

             self.heightMeasurement = "\(height)"
             self.widthMeasurement = "\(width)"
             print(height, width)
        }
        else {
             self.heightMeasurement = "" //set some default value
             self.widthMeasurement = ""  //set some default value
        }
        self.key = snapshot.key     
    }
}
```

**Note:** If your array having more than two objects than to get the `height` and `width` you need to subscripting the array index first to get the dictionary and then access its key according to get your value.

Comment: Thank you for this Nirav but it hasn't seemed solved my issue. Nothing gets printed from the code you have provided.

Comment: @Chace Try once replacing `[[String:Int]]` with `[[String:Any]]`

Comment: Ok, it works and prints out the values. But how do I call this on lets say a UIlabel. I've tried cell.heightLbl.text = item.measurement but nothing happens and pretty sure is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, I'll make it more clear I want the separate labels to display how many values measurement has (in this case 2). And display these values, so height = "30" and width = "50".

Comment: @Chace Check the edited answer and now you can set it like `cell.heightLbl.text = item.heightMeasurement` same goes for width

Comment: @Chace Greats :) Glad it works for you also I edited `[[String:Int]]` to `[[String:Any]]`